# UK Visitor Visa possible refusal?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

[image]

We have just received this email regarding my partners UK visitor visa application. I know that we should just wait the 3 days for him to collect his passport to see the outcome, but I can’t help but wonder if this email means he has been rejected? I’ve been doing some research and I’ve came across forums where people have said they have received different worded emails based on the outcomes of their visa applications.

I just want to get everybody’s comments or experiences...

Comment: There is no information regarding the success or failure of your application contained in this message. You will have to wait for the documents to arrive.

Comment: These messages are stock and deliberately contain no information specific to the application as that may leak PII through unauthorised means - literally, the message says what it says.  Thats it.  No need to read anything into it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had seen a post on this website from May that would suggest differently, some people seem to have received emails (from the same decision making office) but the email contained “the outcome of your application has been successful and dispatched” & I became panicked! As obviously his email does not include any word of “successful”.                                 It’s a visa for him to meet his son once born, so it’s very important.